# Slow performance and index not taken into consideration in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

I'll post my query plan, view and indexes at the bottom of the page so that I can keep this question as clean as possible.

The issue I have is slow performance for a view that is not using indexes as I would expect them to be used. I have a table with around 7 million rows that I use as source for the view below.

I have added an index on **eventdate** which is being used as expected, but why is the index on **manufacturerkey** ignored? Which indexes would be more efficient?

Also, is it maybe this part  `to_char(fe.eventdate, 'HH24:MI'::text) AS hourminutes` that hurts the performance?

Query plan: https://explain.dalibo.com/plan/Pvw

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW public.v_test
AS SELECT df.facilityname,
    dd.date,
    dt.military_hour AS hour,
    to_char(fe.eventdate, 'HH24:MI'::text) AS hourminutes,
    df.tenantid,
    df.tenantname,
    dev.name AS event_type_name,
    dtt.name AS ticket_type_name,
    dde.name AS device_type_name,
    count(*) AS count,
    dl.country,
    dl.state,
    dl.district,
    ds.systemmanufacturer
   FROM fact_entriesexits fe
     JOIN dim_facility df ON df.key = fe.facilitykey
     JOIN dim_date dd ON dd.key = fe.datekey
     JOIN dim_time dt ON dt.key = fe.timekey
     LEFT JOIN dim_device dde ON dde.key = fe.devicekey
     JOIN dim_eventtype dev ON dev.key = fe.eventtypekey
     JOIN dim_tickettype dtt ON dtt.key = fe.tickettypekey
     JOIN dim_licenseplate dl ON dl.key = fe.licenseplatekey
     LEFT JOIN dim_systeminterface ds ON ds.key = fe.systeminterfacekey
  WHERE fe.manufacturerkey = ANY (ARRAY[2, 1])
  AND fe.eventdate >= '2022-01-01'
  GROUP BY df.tenantname, df.tenantid, dl.region, dl.country, dl.state, 
  dl.district, df.facilityname, dev.name, dtt.name, dde.name,
  ds.systemmanufacturer, dd.date, dt.military_hour, (to_char(fe.eventdate, 'HH24:MI'::text)), fe.licenseplatekey;
```

Here are the indexes the table fact_entriesexits contains:

```
CREATE INDEX idx_devicetype_fact_entriesexits_202008 ON public.fact_entriesexits_202008 USING btree (devicetype)
CREATE INDEX idx_etlsource_fact_entriesexits_202008 ON public.fact_entriesexits_202008 USING btree (etlsource)
CREATE INDEX idx_eventdate_fact_entriesexits_202008 ON public.fact_entriesexits_202008 USING btree (eventdate)
CREATE INDEX idx_fact_entriesexits_202008 ON public.fact_entriesexits_202008 USING btree (datekey)
CREATE INDEX idx_manufacturerkey_202008 ON public.fact_entriesexits_202008 USING btree (manufacturerkey)
```

Query plan:

```
Subquery Scan on v_lpr2  (cost=505358.60..508346.26 rows=17079 width=340) (actual time=85619.542..109797.440 rows=3008065 loops=1)
  Buffers: shared hit=91037 read=366546, temp read=83669 written=83694
  ->  Finalize GroupAggregate  (cost=505358.60..508175.47 rows=17079 width=359) (actual time=85619.539..109097.943 rows=3008065 loops=1)
        Group Key: df.tenantname, df.tenantid, dl.region, dl.country, dl.state, dl.district, df.facilityname, dev.name, dtt.name, dde.name, ds.systemmanufacturer, dd.date, dt.military_hour, (to_char(fe.eventdate, 'HH24:MI'::text)), fe.licenseplatekey
        Buffers: shared hit=91037 read=366546, temp read=83669 written=83694
        ->  Gather Merge  (cost=505358.60..507392.70 rows=14232 width=359) (actual time=85619.507..105395.429 rows=3308717 loops=1)
              Workers Planned: 2
              Workers Launched: 2
              Buffers: shared hit=91037 read=366546, temp read=83669 written=83694
              ->  Partial GroupAggregate  (cost=504358.57..504749.95 rows=7116 width=359) (actual time=85169.770..94043.715 rows=1102906 loops=3)
                    Group Key: df.tenantname, df.tenantid, dl.region, dl.country, dl.state, dl.district, df.facilityname, dev.name, dtt.name, dde.name, ds.systemmanufacturer, dd.date, dt.military_hour, (to_char(fe.eventdate, 'HH24:MI'::text)), fe.licenseplatekey
                    Buffers: shared hit=91037 read=366546, temp read=83669 written=83694
                    ->  Sort  (cost=504358.57..504376.36 rows=7116 width=351) (actual time=85169.748..91995.088 rows=1500405 loops=3)
                          Sort Key: df.tenantname, df.tenantid, dl.region, dl.country, dl.state, dl.district, df.facilityname, dev.name, dtt.name, dde.name, ds.systemmanufacturer, dd.date, dt.military_hour, (to_char(fe.eventdate, 'HH24:MI'::text)), fe.licenseplatekey
                          Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 218752kB
                          Buffers: shared hit=91037 read=366546, temp read=83669 written=83694
                          ->  Hash Left Join  (cost=3904.49..503903.26 rows=7116 width=351) (actual time=52.894..46338.295 rows=1500405 loops=3)
                                Hash Cond: (fe.systeminterfacekey = ds.key)
                                Buffers: shared hit=90979 read=366546
                                ->  Hash Join  (cost=3886.89..503848.87 rows=7116 width=321) (actual time=52.458..44551.012 rows=1500405 loops=3)
                                      Hash Cond: (fe.licenseplatekey = dl.key)
                                      Buffers: shared hit=90943 read=366546
                                      ->  Hash Left Join  (cost=3849.10..503792.31 rows=7116 width=269) (actual time=51.406..43869.673 rows=1503080 loops=3)
                                            Hash Cond: (fe.devicekey = dde.key)
                                            Buffers: shared hit=90870 read=366546
                                            ->  Hash Join  (cost=3405.99..503330.51 rows=7116 width=255) (actual time=47.077..43258.069 rows=1503080 loops=3)
                                                  Hash Cond: (fe.timekey = dt.key)
                                                  Buffers: shared hit=90021 read=366546
                                                  ->  Hash Join  (cost=570.97..500476.80 rows=7116 width=257) (actual time=6.869..42345.723 rows=1503080 loops=3)
                                                        Hash Cond: (fe.datekey = dd.key)
                                                        Buffers: shared hit=87348 read=366546
                                                        ->  Hash Join  (cost=166.75..500053.90 rows=7116 width=257) (actual time=2.203..41799.463 rows=1503080 loops=3)
                                                              Hash Cond: (fe.facilitykey = df.key)
                                                              Buffers: shared hit=86787 read=366546
                                                              ->  Hash Join  (cost=2.72..499871.14 rows=7116 width=224) (actual time=0.362..41103.372 rows=1503085 loops=3)
                                                                    Hash Cond: (fe.tickettypekey = dtt.key)
                                                                    Buffers: shared hit=86427 read=366546
                                                                    ->  Hash Join  (cost=1.14..499722.81 rows=54741 width=214) (actual time=0.311..40595.537 rows=1503085 loops=3)
                                                                          Hash Cond: (fe.eventtypekey = dev.key)
                                                                          Buffers: shared hit=86424 read=366546
                                                                          ->  Append  (cost=0.00..494830.25 rows=1824733 width=40) (actual time=0.266..40015.860 rows=1503085 loops=3)
                                                                                Buffers: shared hit=86421 read=366546
                                                                                ->  Parallel Seq Scan on fact_entriesexits fe  (cost=0.00..0.00 rows=1 width=40) (actual time=0.001..0.001 rows=0 loops=3)
                                                                                      Filter: ((manufacturerkey = ANY ('{2,1}'::integer[])) AND (eventdate >= '2022-01-01 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone))
                                                                                ->  Parallel Index Scan using idx_eventdate_fact_entriesexits_202101 on fact_entriesexits_202101 fe_25  (cost=0.42..4.28 rows=1 width=40) (actual time=0.005..0.006 rows=0 loops=3)
                                                                                      Index Cond: (eventdate >= '2022-01-01 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone)
                                                                                      Filter: (manufacturerkey = ANY ('{2,1}'::integer[]))
                                                                                      Buffers: shared hit=3
                                                                                ->  Parallel Index Scan using idx_eventdate_fact_entriesexits_202102 on fact_entriesexits_202102 fe_26  (cost=0.42..4.27 rows=1 width=40) (actual time=0.005..0.006 rows=0 loops=3)
                                                                                      Index Cond: (eventdate >= '2022-01-01 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone)
                                                                                      Filter: (manufacturerkey = ANY ('{2,1}'::integer[]))
                                                                                      Buffers: shared hit=3
                                                                                ->  Parallel Index Scan using idx_eventdate_fact_entriesexits_202103 on fact_entriesexits_202103 fe_27  (cost=0.42..4.24 rows=1 width=40) (actual time=0.007..0.007 rows=0 loops=3)
                                                                                      Index Cond: (eventdate >= '2022-01-01 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone)
                                                                                      Filter: (manufacturerkey = ANY ('{2,1}'::integer[]))
                                                                                      Buffers: shared hit=3
                                                                                ->  Parallel Index Scan using idx_eventdate_fact_entriesexits_202104 on fact_entriesexits_202104 fe_28  (cost=0.42..4.05 rows=1 width=40) (actual time=0.006..0.006 rows=0 loops=3)
                                                                                      Index Cond: (eventdate >= '2022-01-01 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone)
                                                                                      Filter: (manufacturerkey = ANY ('{2,1}'::integer[]))
                                                                                      Buffers: shared hit=3
                                                                                ->  Parallel Index Scan using idx_eventdate_fact_entriesexits_202105 on fact_entriesexits_202105 fe_29  (cost=0.43..4.12 rows=1 width=40) (actual time=0.006..0.006 rows=0 loops=3)
                                                                                      Index Cond: (eventdate >= '2022-01-01 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone)
                                                                                      Filter: (manufacturerkey = ANY ('{2,1}'::integer[]))
                                                                                      Buffers: shared hit=3
                                                                                ->  Parallel Index Scan using idx_eventdate_fact_entriesexits_202106 on fact_entriesexits_202106 fe_30  (cost=0.43..4.19 rows=1 width=40) (actual time=0.005..0.006 rows=0 loops=3)
                                                                                      Index Cond: (eventdate >= '2022-01-01 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone)
                                                                                      Filter: (manufacturerkey = ANY ('{2,1}'::integer[]))
                                                                                      Buffers: shared hit=3
                                                                                ->  Parallel Index Scan using idx_eventdate_fact_entriesexits_202107 on fact_entriesexits_202107 fe_31  (cost=0.43..4.28 rows=1 width=40) (actual time=0.005..0.006 rows=0 loops=3)
                                                                                      Index Cond: (eventdate >= '2022-01-01 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone)
                                                                                      Filter: (manufacturerkey = ANY ('{2,1}'::integer[]))
                                                                                      Buffers: shared hit=3
                                                                                ->  Parallel Index Scan using idx_eventdate_fact_entriesexits_202108 on fact_entriesexits_202108 fe_32  (cost=0.43..3.83 rows=1 width=40) (actual time=0.007..0.007 rows=0 loops=3)
                                                                                      Index Cond: (eventdate >= '2022-01-01 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone)
                                                                                      Filter: (manufacturerkey = ANY ('{2,1}'::integer[]))
                                                                                      Buffers: shared hit=3
                                                                                ->  Parallel Index Scan using idx_eventdate_fact_entriesexits_202109 on fact_entriesexits_202109 fe_33  (cost=0.43..3.40 rows=1 width=40) (actual time=0.006..0.007 rows=0 loops=3)
                                                                                      Index Cond: (eventdate >= '2022-01-01 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone)
                                                                                      Filter: (manufacturerkey = ANY ('{2,1}'::integer[]))
                                                                                      Buffers: shared hit=3
                                                                                ->  Parallel Index Scan using idx_eventdate_fact_entriesexits_202110 on fact_entriesexits_202110 fe_34  (cost=0.43..2.77 rows=1 width=40) (actual time=0.005..0.005 rows=0 loops=3)
                                                                                      Index Cond: (eventdate >= '2022-01-01 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone)
                                                                                      Filter: (manufacturerkey = ANY ('{2,1}'::integer[]))
                                                                                      Buffers: shared hit=3
                                                                                ->  Parallel Index Scan using idx_eventdate_fact_entriesexits_202111 on fact_entriesexits_202111 fe_35  (cost=0.43..3.21 rows=1 width=40) (actual time=0.005..0.005 rows=0 loops=3)
                                                                                      Index Cond: (eventdate >= '2022-01-01 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone)
                                                                                      Filter: (manufacturerkey = ANY ('{2,1}'::integer[]))
                                                                                      Buffers: shared hit=3
                                                                                ->  Parallel Index Scan using idx_eventdate_fact_entriesexits_202112 on fact_entriesexits_202112 fe_36  (cost=0.43..3.45 rows=1 width=40) (actual time=0.004..0.004 rows=0 loops=3)
                                                                                      Index Cond: (eventdate >= '2022-01-01 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone)
                                                                                      Filter: (manufacturerkey = ANY ('{2,1}'::integer[]))
                                                                                      Buffers: shared hit=3
                                                                                ->  Parallel Seq Scan on fact_entriesexits_202201 fe_37  (cost=0.00..382550.76 rows=445931 width=40) (actual time=0.032..39090.092 rows=379902 loops=3)
                                                                                      Filter: ((manufacturerkey = ANY ('{2,1}'::integer[])) AND (eventdate >= '2022-01-01 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone))
                                                                                      Rows Removed by Filter: 298432
                                                                                      Buffers: shared hit=3286 read=366546
                                                                                ->  Parallel Seq Scan on fact_entriesexits_202204 fe_38  (cost=0.00..39567.99 rows=469653 width=40) (actual time=0.015..242.895 rows=375639 loops=3)
                                                                                      Filter: ((manufacturerkey = ANY ('{2,1}'::integer[])) AND (eventdate >= '2022-01-01 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone))
                                                                                      Rows Removed by Filter: 158868
                                                                                      Buffers: shared hit=29546
                                                                                ->  Parallel Seq Scan on fact_entriesexits_202202 fe_39  (cost=0.00..30846.99 rows=437343 width=40) (actual time=0.019..230.952 rows=357451 loops=3)
                                                                                      Filter: ((manufacturerkey = ANY ('{2,1}'::integer[])) AND (eventdate >= '2022-01-01 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone))
                                                                                      Rows Removed by Filter: 98708
                                                                                      Buffers: shared hit=22294
```

Comment: Your plan again seems to be truncated.  each hash join should have two child nodes, but yours just have one.

Comment: I did an EXPLAIN (BUFFERS, ANALYZE) on the query, is it maybe because I'm selecting the view and not the query inside the view?

Comment: The view wouldn't cause that.  Maybe your tool truncated it, or when you copy and pasted it you only grabbed the first screen/page.

Comment: try to use subquery and reduce no of columns from group by clause if possible.

Answer (score 0):

Your slowest seq scan step is returning over half the rows of its partition, removing 298432 and returning 379902.  (times around 3 each due to parallel workers).  An index is unlikely to be helpful when returning so much of the table rows anyway.

Note that that partition also seems to be massively bloated.  It is hard to see why else it would be so slow, and require so many buffer reads compared to the number of rows.